# identify last element of an array in Groovy 'for' statement

Tags: arrays, for-loop, groovy

Is it possible to identify the last element of an array within a 'for' statement like the following?

```
for (ai in list) {


}
```

It's not a requirement, it's mainly curiosity.

Comment: `eachWithIndex` or a for loop with an index is a better choice if you need to do this

Comment: Or perhaps an iterator

Comment: @Dónal agree, but that's not what I'm asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can with enough trickery (i.e. metaprogramming). The classes below define a custom iterator that dynamically injects a readonly `last` property into each element and a custom List implementation for returning the custom iterator.

```
import groovy.transform.TupleConstructor

@TupleConstructor
class LastAwareIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    Iterator itr
    boolean hasNext() {
        itr.hasNext()
    }

    void remove() {
        itr.remove()
    }

    T next() {
        T obj = itr.next()
        boolean last = !itr.hasNext()
        obj.metaClass.isLast << { -> last }
        obj
    }
}

class LastAwareList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    Iterator<T> iterator() {
        new LastAwareIterator(super.iterator())
    }
}
```

When you coerce your list into `LastAwareList` using `as`, you can use the `last` property within the for loop body.

```
def list = [1,2,3,4,2] as LastAwareList
for (ai in list) {
    if (ai.last) {
        print 'and '
    }
    print "$ai "
}
// prints 1 2 3 4 and 2
```

I had originally wanted to use ExpandoMetaClass to directly override the `iterator` method, avoiding the need for `as LastAwareList`, but couldn't get it working. If I ever figure it out, I'll update the post.

Answer (score 3):

I know it isn't what you asked,  but I just want to bring to your attention that in groovy there is a really cool way of getting the last element.

```
def list = [1,2,3]
println list.last()
```

Answer (score 2):

A counter has to be maintained to check the last item in the list.

```
def printList(list) {
    int x = 1
    for ( ai in list ) {
        if ( x == list.size() ) println "and"
        println ai
        x++
    }
    println ""
}

printList([1,2,3,4,5])
printList([1,2,3,4,2])
printList([2,2,2])
printList([])
printList(null)
```

Also try with list having duplicate elements and the last item being a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def list = [1,2,3,4,5,6] //your list
def last = list.last() //got last item of list
list.each { item ->
    if (item == last) { //checking last item
        println ("and "+ item)
    } else {
        println(item)
    }
}
//result : 1 2 3 4 5 and 6
```

Comment: You should always add an explanation of your code, just posting a code snippet encourages people to copy/paste things they don't understand and doesn't help them learn.